# Does h2o4gpu handle categorical features like sklearn or like h2o?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, h2o, h2o4gpu

I understand that `sklearn` requires categorical features to be encoded to dummy variables or one-hot encoded when running the `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor` method, and that `XGBoost` requires the same, but `h2o` permitted raw categorical features to be used in its `h2o.estimators.random_forest.H2ORandomForestEstimator` method. Since `h2o4gpu`'s implementation of random forest is built on top of `XGBoost`, does this mean support for raw categorical features is not included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support for categorical columns in **h2o4gpu** (at least yet), so you will have to one-hot encode (or label encode) your categorical columns like you do in **sklearn** and **xgboost**.

Comment: Is there a reason for this that I can read about online? The main advantage of `h2o` for me was its use of categorical features...

Comment: The reason is that **h2o4gpu** was released only a few months ago.  It's alpha and many features are not complete yet.